# Combining URI_REQUEST and HTTP_HOST in an .htaccess file

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite, url-shortener

I'd like to do link shortening using PHP and Apache/.htaccess.

Here's how a link on my site looks:

https://mysite.com/item/this-is-a-book-on-toasters

Here's how I'd like the shortened link to look for the above link.

https://ms.co/Im8y2x

Currently, this is what I have in my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^ms\.co$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://mysite.com/item/$1 [L,R=301]
```

So going to ms.co does redirect to mysite.com. My problem is that my PHP code at mysite.com/item has no knowledge of the 6 digit string (in this case, `Im8y2x`) so I can't query my database for the 6 digit string's matching URI (in this case, `/this-is-a-book-on-toasters`).

I know I need something added to my .htaccess Rewrite rules I'm just not sure what it is. Might someone be able to help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out my own question. If you just leave out `R=301` then you'll preserve the URI (in this case, `Im8y2x`) and then you can access it with your scripting language (in my case, PHP) to redirect it to the full length URI.

So **instead** of this:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://mysite.com/item/$1 [L,R=301]
```

do this:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://mysite.com/item/$1 [L] 
// the only difference is the lack of ",R=301"
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^ms\.co/$1 [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://mysite.com/item/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: hmm, after adding `/$1` now it's not redirecting to https://mysite.com so I think that's not correct.

Comment: hi @Robert, any more suggestions?